# Gatsby Algolia tag based search

Tags: gatsby, algolia

In Gatsby, using Algolia, I can get the text search to work properly with search results linking properly to their blog posts.

Each blog post has a footer. In this footer there are keywords. Is it possible to click on a keyword, then be routed to a results page with all the matching blog posts that have the same keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include the tag or key word as a part of your `frontmatter` instead like is described [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-tags-and-categories-to-blog-posts/). Then in your algolia query include that field from your `frontmatter` in GraphQL query and it will be able to search based on those tags.